# Mysql Select with two SUM from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I'm trying to select SUMed data from two tables.
This is how they look.

Table1:

```
products | revenue|
------------------|
product1 | 10     |
product2 | 20     |
product1 | 20     |
```

Table2:

```
products | revenue|
------------------|
product1 | 40     |
product2 | 30     |
product2 | 40     |
```

So the query should sum them like this:

```
products | revenue|
------------------|
product1 | 70     |
product2 | 90     |
```

I've tried this and some other queries but they are incorrect.

```
SELECT  Table1.products, Table1.SUM(`revenue`), Table2.SUM(`revenue`)
FROM    Table1
JOIN    Table2
ON      Table1.products = Table2.products
group by Table1.products;
```

Could you help me, what is the right query in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL and SUM aggregate function :

```
 SELECT products , SUM(revenue) revenue
 FROM
 (
   SELECT products  , revenue
   FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT products  , revenue
   FROM table2
 ) A
 GROUP BY products
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `union all` and then `group by`:

```
select product, sum(revenue)
from ((select product, revenue from table1) union all
      (select product, revenue from table2)
     ) tt
group by product;
```

This will ensure that all products are in the result set, even products that are only in one table.